# Proving integrability of a non-negative function using a negative lower bound

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Suppose one has the following function $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$:

$$ f(t) = \prod_{k =1}^{K} \left[p_k(t) \right]^{m_{k}}\frac{1}{t}, $$
where $m_k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, M$ such that $\sum_k m_k = M$, and 
$$  0 \leq p_k(t) :=  \sum_{v = 1}^V w_{kv} \exp(t\lambda_v) \leq 1, $$
with $w_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda_k \leq 0$.
Also, we have $\sum_k p_k(t) = 1$ because the $p_k$s come from a stochastic matrix.

I want suspect that
$$ \int_0^\infty f(t) \,dt = \infty.$$

**Attempt at proof**:
The idea is to find a lower bound $g(t)$ for $f(t)$ and show that $ \int_0^\infty g(t) \,dt = \infty$. 
To that end, for each $k$ take
$$  h_k(t) = \alpha_k\exp(-\beta_kt)  := \min_v w_{kv} \exp(t\lambda_v) \leq p_k(t) ,$$
but notice that it's possible $h_k(t) \leq 0$.
Now we can write 
$$g(t) = \prod_{k =1}^{K} \left[ h_k(t) \right]^{m_{k}}\frac{1}{t} = \frac{\alpha^\prime\exp(-\beta^\prime t_i)}{t}, $$
with $\alpha^\prime = \prod_k \alpha_k^{m_k}$ and $\beta^\prime = \sum_k m_k \beta_k$.
Finally, recall that a function $g$ integrable iff $|g|$ is integrable and compute
$$ \int_0^\infty  \left|\frac{\alpha^\prime \exp(-\beta^\prime t)}{t} \right| \, dt =   \infty,  $$
to conclude the (presumed) proof.

> **Question**: is this correct? If not, what other approach(es) could I take?  It might be that $f$ is indeed integrable, but, in that case, how do I show it?

### Example

One simple special case is

$$ f(t) = \left[ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} e^{-\alpha t} \right]^{N-x} \left[ \frac{3}{4} - \frac{3}{4} e^{-\alpha t} \right]^x \frac{1}{t} $$
with $\alpha = 4/3$ and $x , N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \leq N$.

### A further idea

I think this can be shown some other way. Namely, by using integration by parts. Let $g(t) = \prod_{k =1}^{K} \left[p_k(t) \right]^{m_{k}}$ and then compute 
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{g(t)}{t} \, dt = \left|g(t)\log(t)\right|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty g^\prime(t) \log(t)\, dt.$$

So if one could show that  $\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = a \leq 1$, which I believe is true, one could then show that the integral of interest diverges.

Comment: Sorry, but I have a bunch of clarifying questions...$K,M$ are fixed? My instinct says $w_{kv}$ has $v$ as a second index, so it is not defined, only $w_k$ is. Or  is it $w_{k\times v}$...? When you say $m_k=0,1,\dots,M$, do you mean $m_1 = 0 , m_2 = 1, m_3 = 2,\dots, m_M = M-1$....and then what happens if $K>M$? How does it follow that $\sum_k p_k(t) = 1$ from the lines before?

Comment: Obviously $p_k \equiv 0$ for at least one $k$ is an option under the given assumptions  (setting $w_{kv} = 0$ for all $k,v$) and at least for this $f\equiv 0$ is integrable. But if you have $w_{kv} > 0$ it's easy to show the integral diverges.

Comment: @CalvinKhor sorry for being unclear. I hope the example I added, along with the further edits and the idea I put in will help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the integral can differ depending on the choice of the $w_{kv}$.

If we have $w_{kv} \equiv 0$ for one $k$ we get $f\equiv 0$ what's obviously integrable.

If we have $w_{kv} > 0$ for all $k,v$ we get:

$f(t) \ge 0$ hence $$\int_0^\infty f(t) \,dt  \ge \int_1^\infty f(t) \,dt$$

But for $t \in [1,\infty)$ it holds: $$p_k(t) :=  \sum_{v = 1}^V w_{kv} \exp(t\lambda_v) \ge \sum_{v = 1}^V w_{kv} \exp(\lambda_v) = p_k(1)$$

And so with $$c:= \prod_{k =1}^{K} \left[p_k(1) \right]^{m_{k}}$$ it holds

$$\int_0^\infty f(t) \,dt  \ge \int_1^\infty f(t) \,dt \ge c\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t} \,dt = +\infty$$

Comment: This answer shows promise. If you could take a look at the edits I made and see if your arguments need to be modified, I'd appreciate it. Alternatively, you can look at the "Further idea" I posted and see if it makes any sense.